# SSRS - Delay Dataset queries

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

So, I have my report written and all is well. However now I have deployed to my live environment I have a problem; when the report is initially opened it runs all the dataset queries, as I have a large database the report is taking an age to display.

Is there a way to prevent all queries running when the report is initially opened? Would like to run just a single dataset query the populates my first parameter, so the user can begin to filter the data before selecting "View Report" to run the main dataset query with the parameters applied rather than getting everything the instant the report is opened?

I have tried setting default values in the parameters to reduce the initial data load but this seems to have confused the users, so think a blank report with nothing selected in the parameters to start with would be better.

Thanks

FTD

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Reporting Services report from rendering automatically on startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820679/how-to-stop-reporting-services-report-from-rendering-automatically-on-startup)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some form of following.

```
QueryLookupState  --  Used to fill dropdownlist etc.
QueryLookupCity   -- Used to fill dropdownlist etc.

QueryMain , your main query which uses parameters from above.
```

You gave default parameters to your report therefore SSRS is using that defaults and running your main query to generate report. Change your main query and default parameters so that your main query bring empty result or main query **needs** parameters from lookups.

You can look following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277714/sql-server-reporting-services-how-to-stop-a-report-firing-when-opened) and answer for same problem. You need at least one non-default parameter, otherwise SSRS will execute your report when it first opened.

Comment: Thanks Atilla, you are correct in that the default values for the parameters are all available values. While the SSRS designer works with null parameters, the app I deploy the report to throws an error if there are no default values selected for a parameter or the parameter query returns no results as subsequent parameters are NULL.